# compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0' makes some resources error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am modifying a android studio project for adding Marshmallow permission.

I have 2 java files

Perijinan.java

```
public class Perijinan extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
    public static int status;
    int REQUEST_CODE;
    private View mLayout;

    public Perijinan() {
        this.REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    }

    static {
        status = 0;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView((int) R.layout.dialog_url);
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            status = 1;
        } else if (checkSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == 0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            status = 1;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}, this.REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == this.REQUEST_CODE && grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == 0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

BlockGraphView.java

```
public class BlockGraphView extends View
{
    private static int BLOCKS_PER_LINE = 15;

    private int mForeground, mBackground;
    private int mBlockSize, mLineCount;
    private DownloadMission mMission;

    public BlockGraphView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public BlockGraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public BlockGraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        try {
            TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Theme);
            mBackground = array.getColor(R.styleable.Theme_colorPrimary, 0);
            mForeground = array.getColor(R.styleable.Theme_colorPrimaryDark, 0);
            array.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

My Gradle file is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "us.myapp.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.1.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.+'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.0.5'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Here is my issue in detail.

If I use compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'` and compile `'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'` in the gradle file, I got error inside Perijinan.java which shows Error on

> OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, requestPermissions etc.

It can be solved by changing the compile to `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'` and `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'`.

But If I use `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'` and `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'`,  I got Error at

> BlockGraphView.java under  mBackground = array.getColor(R.styleable.Theme_colorPrimary, 0); and mForeground = array.getColor(R.styleable.Theme_colorPrimaryDark, 0); [R.styleable.Theme_colorPrimaryDark, R.styleable.Theme_colorPrimary as red marked]

How can I solve this?

Comment: When you use 23.2.0, what error it shows when you hover over red underlined content?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol Theme_colorPrimary Cannot resolve symbol Theme_colorPrimaryDark

Comment: why don't you use `R.color.colorPrimary` or `R.color.colorPrimaryDark` instead? It seems like the IDE can't find those stylables....

Answer (score 0):

Please rename your support library dependencies in the below pattern and check as this may help you .Also instead of hardcoding it picks the latest update .

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion'